# Node JS 0.6.1 msi on Windows

Tags: windows, node.js

How do I use NodeJS on Windows? I've downloaded and installed the 0.6.1 MSI.

I can run node in the command prompt.

What do I do next? I can't seem to find much information such as where to put files etc

It's just for a little experimentation.

Thanks

Ric

Comment: have you looked at this site https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki

Comment: I have done. It's installed, and I can run in a command prompt. I read somewhere about passing the location of a JS file so I did that (using a sample file), but it just shows me three dots ... and the page can not be found in the browser.

Comment: "passing the location of a JS file" does not mean typing it in into node prompt after running node, but specifying it as a parameter when launching node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was being an idiot. I was running node at c: then typing the full path to the file within Node! If any one has the same problem then make sure you change to the folder your js files are in first, then node filename.js

Comment: Still unclear.  Where are you supposed to put your first JS file?  Or how do I open node from that folder?

Answer (score 4):

Have you followed the basic tutorial exactly as it is posted?  If you create a file (let's say, index.js) that looks like this...

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(204, { 'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
    res.write('Hello World');
    res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

...and then launch it via the command line like so (assumes `index.js` is visible from the current directory)...

```
node index.js
```

...you should see `Hello World` in your browser when you point it to `http://localhost:8080`.

If you simply run `node` then you will get an interactive javascript shell, which is not what you want.

Make sure you called `listen(port)` and also make sure that you called `res.end()` in order to send the response.